# Error en Zeppelin con intérprete Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Cassandra me da el error '%cassandra  select * from mykeyspace.users ; java.io.IOException: Invalid argument' cuando ejecuto una query SELECT (Tengo arrancado zeppelin y cassandra en línea (MS-DOS)

Comment: ¿tienes una nueva línea después de `% cassandra`?
¿Qué versión de Zeppelin y Cassandra?

PD lo siento, se hace a través de Google Translate ...

Answer (score 0):

las versiones son: *Cassandra 3.11.6* y *Zeppelin 0.8.2*.

La instrucción que ejecuto es `%cassandra HELP;` La primera vez aparece el error de 'Argumento inválido', y la segunda aparece el error comentado:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.apache.zeppelin.cassandra.DisplaySystem$NoResultDisplay$